# Scheduled database maintenance with Java EE 6 (connection lifetime)

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, mybatis

I'm new to Java EE 6 so I apologize if the answer to this question is obvious. I have a task that must run hourly to rebuild a Solr index from a database. I also want the rebuild to occur when the app is deployed. My gut instinct is that this should work:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Rebuilder {
  @Inject private ProposalDao proposalDao;
  @Inject private SolrServer  solrServer;

  @Schedule(hour="*", minute="0", second="0")
  public void rebuildIndex() {
    // do the rebuild here
  }
}
```

Since I'm using myBatis, I have written this producer:

```
public class ProposalSessionProvider {
  private static final String CONFIGURATION_FILE = "...";

  static {
    try {
      sessFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(
        Resources.getResourceAsReader(CONFIGURATION_FILE));
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error configuring MyBatis: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
  }

  @Produces
  public ProposalsDao openSession() {
    log.info("Connecting to the database");
    session = sessFactory.openSession();
    return session.getMapper(ProposalsDao.class);
  }
}
```

So I have three concerns:

1. What's the appropriate way to trigger a rebuild at deployment time? A `@PostConstruct` method?
2. Who is responsible for closing the database connection, and how should that happen? I'm using myBatis which is, I believe, pretty ignorant of the Java EE lifecycle. It seems like if I use `@Singleton` the connections will never be released, but is it even meaningful to put `@Startup` on a `@Stateless` bean?
3. Should the Rebuilder be a singleton or not? It seems like if it is not I couldn't use `@PostConstruct` to handle the initial rebuild or I'll get double rebuilds every hour.

I'm not really sure how to proceed here. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know myBatis but i can tell you than @Schedule job is transactional. Anyway i'am not sure that JTA managed transaction will apply here according to the way you retrieve the session.
 Isn't there a way to retrieve a persistenceContext in MyBatis ? 
 For the trigger part IMHO @Startup will do the job properly and will need a singleton bean so. Anyway i'am not able to tell you which of the 2 methods you propose is the best one.

Comment: No, myBatis is not a JPA compatible ORM. There are integration libraries for Spring and Guide, but not Java EE.

Comment: So you will have to expose your sessionFactory to your singleton in order to manage transactions manually. Other solution is to switch to spring to use spring managed transaction or switch to a JPA implementation instead of myBatis

Comment: What would it take to wrap up myBatis in a way that it could at least use container-managed transactions, if not be JPA? I'm not interested in deploying Spring or switching to JPA; I'll accept manual transactions if I have to but I'd still rather they be container-managed.

Comment: If you can't get a proper JPA entityManager (`@PersistenceContext`) then you can sit on JPA Managed transaction, sorry.

Comment: My understanding is that container transaction management is JTA, not JPA, and it should be possible to coordinate transactions with non-JPA datasources. I can understand (to a degree) not being able to inject an `@PersistenceContext` without JPA, but does that mean I'm shut out completely from container managed transactions? Java EE seems more flexible than this. I suspect my options aren't quite as dire as you're presenting.

Comment: JTA defines transaction api which include user and container managed transaction. You don't need JPA to use JTA user transaction but you need it to provide a container managed persistence context. JEE ORM implements many JSR not only the JPA one. As MyBatis does not integrate within a jee container you will have to provide yourself the integration implementation or to use user-managed transaction

Comment: What do I need to do to provide the integration implementation myself?

Comment: honestly i have no idea, imho it's a project itself and you shouldn't go this way except if you have lot of free time and motivation. You can start by looking at MyBatis-Spring module which do the same things for spring managed transaction. maybe start a collaborative open source project cause it seems to me a huge piece of work. Good luck

Comment: This conversation is exactly like the one in the Monty Python sketch "The Cheese Shop" except there's no way for me to shoot you for wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

For the scheduling part, you are correct; I'd write the index building logic in a separate class, and have both a (Singleton?) @StartUp bean and a @Schedule-annotated method in a separate class call it.

JMS could be used by said beans to trigger the index rebuilding, if you don't want to have a dependency between the index-building code, and the triggering code in said classes.

I don't know myBatis well enough, but if your connection is managed by a data source @Resource, then I believe it could indeed benefit from CMT.

Comment: myBatis is completely ignorant of Java EE. Do you know what I would need to do to integrate it and gain CMT?

Comment: Can't help much because I don't know myBatis. Why are you using it on a EE environment in the first place? Wouldn't it be better to either migrate your persistence code to something JPA-compliant, or use myBatis only outside of this context?

Comment: Yes, it's true you can't help much.